# Arithmetic and Geometric Progression (Nth term)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The $n$th term of an arithmetic progression is $T_n$.

Show that $$U_n=\frac{5}{2}(-2)^{2(\frac{10-T_n}{17})}$$ is the $n$th term of a geometric progression.

Can anyone give me some hints or guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Because the exponent is another arithmetic progression.

Comment: Substitute $T_n=a+bn$ into $U_n$, you can easily find $U_n=c(-2)^{dn}$ for some $c,d$

Comment: $U_n=\frac{5}{2}(-2)^{2(\frac{10-a-bn}{17})}$, how to show that $U_n=c(-2)^{dn}$? @MengchunZhang Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mathxx I have updated this in an answer post, let me know if there are mistakes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_n=a+bn$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$, then

$$U_n=\frac52(-2)^{2\left(\frac{10-a-bn}{17}\right)}=\frac52\cdot4^{\frac{10-a-bn}{17}}=\left(\frac52\cdot4^{\frac{10-a}{17}}\right)4^{-\frac{bn}{17}}=c\cdot r^n$$

with the initial term $c=\frac52\cdot4^{\frac{10-a}{17}}$ and common ratio $r=4^{-\frac b{17}}$.

(Note that $b=0$ implies $T_n$ and $U_n$ are constant)

Comment: But wouldn't nth term of geometric progression be $a\cdot r^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Mathxx It depends on whether we start at $n=0$ or $n=1$, if start at $n=1$ then use $r^{n-1}$